# Why is this projection wrong?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I am trying to figure out why a 3D cube doesn't project in the right place in the image.

I start with the camera at origin and the cube centered at `(0,0,1)` world coordinates:

[image: front]

Then I create a 3D rotation `R` of 45 degrees around the Y axis:

```
(0.707106781, 0, 0.707106781,
0, 1, 0,
-0.707106781, 0, 0.707106781)
```

And I set the camera to use rotation `R^-1`, with a translation of `R * (0,0,1)` (these are camera to world transformations). The camera should have rotated 45 degrees CCW around the cube (I can confirm I have `0.707106781` translation on x and z).

At this point, I would expect to see the cube with the same scale, still centered, and with one of the edges right in the middle of the image. But this is what I get:

[image: side-45]

The procedure I use to project a 3d point `X` is (pseudo code):

- bring into camera coordinates: `Xc = R^-1 * X - R^1 * translation`
- transform into image coordinates: `x = Xc * focal length / Xc.z + principal point`

I have read the theory from various sources and it seems I am following the rules.

This is just artificial data, so not sure if focal length and principal point can have any effect on it? What am I doing wrong? Why is the cube not centered?

**EDIT:**

I construct the cube like this (duplicate vertices are there because I need them to draw lines):

```
  cv::Matx31d center(0,0,1);
  double delta = 0.2;

  std::vector<cv::Matx31d> volumeCorners = {
    // back
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, delta, delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, delta, delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, delta, delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, -delta, delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, -delta, delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, -delta, delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, -delta, delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, delta, delta)),

    // right
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, delta, delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, delta, -delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, delta, -delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, -delta, -delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, -delta, -delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, -delta, delta)),

    // front
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, delta, -delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, delta, -delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, -delta, -delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(delta, -delta, -delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, -delta, -delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, delta, -delta)),

    // left
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, delta, -delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, delta, delta)),

    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, -delta, delta)),
    (center + cv::Matx31d(-delta, -delta, -delta)),
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your axis of rotation is the vertical red line on the left in the first diagram rather than the vertical line through the center of mass of the cube (not depicted).

I think you need to check everything again to confirm that the corners of the cube are really where you think they are.

I can add a little more help if you help me with your coordinate system a bit. (Can you label the axes and/or tell me the coordinate of the corners? Different people use different conventions...)

---

If the center of the cube is $(0,0,1)$, it looks to me like the $x-y$ origin is in the center of the picture.

Conceptually, this would be the order things would happen in:

1. translate the cube forward so that its center is along the $y$-axis. You can do this by subtracting $(0,0,1)$ from all of the coordinates.
2. Now apply the rotation matrix to turn the cube (I haven't actually checked the direction it goes, but I trust your computation on that. It looks correct.)
3. Translate the cube back from whence it came by adding $(0,0,1)$ to all the coordinates.

If I can answer questions of translating this into your implementation, ask away.

---

If you believe that the $x-y$ origin is in the upper left hand corner (as standard graphics conventions do) then your cube obviously can't be centered at $(0,0,1)$. The point $(0,0,1)$ would have to be underneath the left hand border of the image. I think if you tried to rotate around the line through $(0,0,1)$ parallel to the $y$-axis, you would be swinging your cube around the left hand border of the picture. That would be consistent with the picture you're producing. So perhaps you are applying the correct transformation, but you have been misinformed about the location of the cube's center.

Comment: I use a right-handed coordinate system, with the y axis pointing down.

Comment: @aledalgrande Er, that's not quite detailed enough, but let me guess the rest: x is across the top, and positive z is into the picture?

Comment: Yeah, sorry: x to the right, y down and z into the picture.

Comment: Also image coordinates: origin at top left corner, x to the right, y down.

Comment: @aledalgrande Actually, I'm a little confused. To me, it looks like your x-y origin is in the center of the picture, with the z-axis receding from view. If your x-y origin is in the upper left, I don't know how the center could be at $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @rscwieb, would you care to elaborate as to why? That could be my problem.

Comment: Oh: the cube is centered at $(0,0,1)$ in _world coordinates_.

Comment: @aledalgrande I added a comment about it. Honestly, I'm a bit lost with camera/world/image coordinates. I'm not sure what corresponds with 'the coordinates" I am thinking of. Don't the camera coordinates only matter to compute the image coordinates? I think my picture of coordinates is the world coordinates, and that if you get those correct, then you can compute the other two sets.

Comment: @aledalgrande At any rate, it seems like you would only want to perform rotations and translations with world coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. The transformations go world->camera->image. It's based on this (PDF): http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture13_6pp.pdf and this (PDF): http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture12_6pp.pdf

Comment: I think your last comment would be correct if I wasn't adding the principal point to the image coordinates. When I divide by the $z$ component of the camera coordinates, I go into 2D film coordinates (or euclidean if you wish), with origin at the center. Then I add the principal point of the camera so that each $x$ and $y$ component of coordinates inside the image is positive. That's why the cube is not up in the corner, but at the center, while the origin is moved to top left.

Answer (score 0):

My translation should have described a rotation around the center of the cube, but it was wrong. I changed it to:

```
rotate45 * (translation - center) + center
```

and I get the cube in the middle with the right angle.